# Using private DBus connection in PyDbus mocks

Tags: python, dbus

There is a service (in the second listing the DBus "coordinates" are given)
running in a Linux environment, and at the same time
I in the tests a custom private DBus is being run as in the following
fixture:

```
def run_custom_daemon():
    cmd = [
        "dbus-daemon",
        "--system",
        "--nofork",
        "--address=unix:path=<some_path>.sock"
    ]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
    os.environ['CUSTOM_DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS'] = "<some_path>.sock"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    yield proc
    proc.kill()
```

Now, my component uses the service `com.foo.bar.Baz` and in the C++-code
I connect to it using the
[`sdbus-c++`](https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp) as e.g.

```
m_prx = stdbus::createProxy(...)
```

Now, if I run the tests as it is it appears that because the "official"
DBus is somehow "shielded" by the tests, I am getting a `ServiceNotKnown`
error. However, if I mock the service using a code below,
I get "the name already has owner"-type of error.
The question is, probably, how to tell the mock to use
the above "privately" set-up DBus?

```
from pydbus import SystemBus
from gi.repository import GLib

class MockSrv:
    dbus = """
        <node name="/com/foo/bar/Baz">
            <interface name="com.foo.bar.Baz">
                <method name="Buzz">
                    <arg type="s" direction="out"/>
                </method>
            </interface>
        </node>
    """

mloop = GLib.MainLoop()
mbus = SystemBus()
srv = MockSrv()
mbus.publish("com.foo.bar.Baz",
            ("/com/foo/bar/Baz", srv)
            )
mloop.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to use Python to mock a DBus service, which you then connect to using C++ for testing.

The best way that I've found to do this is to create a local session bus(using something like [dbus-run-session](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-run-session.1.html)) to run the applications.  This will setup the environment variables correctly to open a new SESSION bus, and then exit at the end.